# Parsing Multiple .json files

Tags: python

I am trying to parse multiple files dealing with "Mike's Pies" as you can see in the code below. I have written it to where I get the desired output, now I would like to parse all the files named "Mike's Pies"

```
 import json
 import sys
 import glob

with open("Mike's Pies.20130201.json") as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
#Keep all orders with variable of r
    for r in data ["orders"]:

        orderName = r["orderPlacer"]["name"]
        #Print with address to acquire the housenumber/street/city/state
        address = r["address"]["houseNumber"]
        street = r["address"]["street"]
        city = r["address"]["city"]
        state = r["address"]["state"]
        Mikes = "Mike's Pies,"
        output = str(orderName) + ", " + str(address) + " " + str(street) +       
         " " + str(city) + " " + str(state) + ", " + Mikes + " " 



        length = len(r["pizzas"])
        for i in range (0,length):
        #if length >= 1 print r["pizzas"][1]["name"]
            #if i!=length:
            pizza = ((r["pizzas"][i]["name"].strip("\n"))).strip(" ")
            if(i!=length-1):
                output += pizza + ", "
            else:
                output += pizza

        print(output+"\n")
```

Comment: You mean you'd like to parse all files named "Mike's Pies.*.json"?  So it's not a JSON or data question, you just want to iterate through files matching a certain criteria?  Lookup os.listdir(), and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have code which works on `"Mike's Pies.20130201.json"`, and you want to run that code on *every* file that starts with "Mike's Pies" and ends with "json", regardless of the timestamp-like bit in the middle. Am I right? You can get all matching filenames with `glob` and parse them one after the other.

```
for filename in glob.glob("Mike's Pies.*.json"):
    with open(filename) as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
        #etc etc... Insert rest of code here
```

Comment: Yes, that's where I was having trouble understand the "glob" func. It works when it parses through all the files, the problem is I am trying figure out how to set it up where it opens a .txt file with all the information that comes out rather than just showing up in the console.